# How to compare a variable with a set (to see if there are duplicates) and if there are, How do i remove them and repeat the process?

Tags: python, set, python-3.7

I'm new here, so I'm sorry if this isn't a good way of asking a question...

This is my code:

```
import random
i = 0
#the numbers of the cards
numbers = ["A","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","Jack","Queen","King"]
#the suits of decks
suits = ["Spades","Hearts","Clubs","Diamonds"]
#empty list
used = []
#Generate random Number and Suit
while i != 5:
    number = random.choice(numbers)
    suit = random.choice(suits)
    print (number+" of "+suit)
    used.append(number + " of " + suit)
    i += 1
```

What I am trying to achieve is to have the code generate a series of 5 cards without duplicates and then printing those...

But I don't know how to get rid of the duplicates and then continue the code...

What I am currently getting is this:

```
King of Spades
King of Spades
Queen of Hearts
A of Clubs
6 of Hearts
['King of Spades', 'King of Spades', 'Queen of Hearts', 'A of Clubs', '6 of Hearts']
```

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: Can't take my typos and bad capitalizations any more. I have to change them...

Comment: Instead of trying to generate random cards, it's usually better to shuffle a deck.

Comment: yeah but my CS homework is this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
import itertools
import random
numbers = ["A","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","Jack","Queen","King"]
#the suits of decks 
suits = ["Spades","Hearts","Clubs","Diamonds"]
deck=list(itertools.product(numbers,suits))
random.shuffle(deck)
for i in range(5):
    print( deck[i][0],'of' ,deck[i][1])
```

Comment: This runs out of suits after four cards.

Comment: @Shadowcodder Thanks but I want to know what exactly did you put to remove the duplicate? (what caused the duplicate to be deleted?)

Comment: I didn't do anything to remove duplicates the line `deck= something` creates every possible combinations in an iterable datatype. I am just print the first five of its value after shuffling it.

Comment: @Shadowcodder Is there any way to print, for example, the next 5 card AFTER the first time(say i was to repeat it)
My Code currently is 
`card = 0
print(deck[i][card+1], deck[i][card])
card += 5`
Does it work like that or is it wrong somehow?

Comment: @s11010 Deck is a list of tuples so you can do anything with it like you do with a list. You can run a for loop for it . `for i in range(5,10): print(deck[i][0],deck[i][1])` . The way you are trying to do it is wrong.

Answer (score 2):

To get rid of duplicating cards, try adding the line as follows:

```
# Generate random Number and Suit
while i != 5:
    number = random.choice(numbers)
    numbers.remove(number) ###
    suit = random.choice(suits)
    print(number + " of " + suit)
    used.append(number + " of " + suit)
    i += 1
```

Comment: If you remove the number, you wont be able to get the same number from different suite.

Answer (score 0):

There is also the solution of using for loops...

```
import random as r

numbers = ["Ace","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","Jack","Queen","King"]
suits = ["Spades","Hearts","Clubs","Diamonds"]

deck = [number + " of " + suit for suit in suits for number in numbers]
r.shuffle(deck)

for i in range(5):
    print(deck[i])
```

Comment: A.K.A. List Comprehension...